# Printing two arguments

Tags: haskell

I am trying to `:load` file "hello.hs" and keep getting the errors below.

I am using  WinGHCi 1.0.6.

I have printed just one argument and it worked but when I try to print two arguments I get a `Not in scope` error as shown below.

My hello.hs code contains the code below.

-----------------hello.hs--------------------

```
module Main where
import System.Environment
main :: IO ( )
main = do 
        args <- getArgs  --Getting first arg
        putStrLn("Hello," ++args!!0)
    do  args1 <- getArgs putStrLn("Hello," ++args1!!1)  --Getting second arg
```

----------Errors while trying to  do  :load command --------

```
hello.hs:6:37: Not in scope: ‘args’

hello.hs:7:13:
    The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
      args1 <- getArgs putStrLn ("Hello," ++ args1 !! 1)

hello.hs:7:50:
    Not in scope: ‘args1’
    Perhaps you meant ‘args’ (line 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the `putStrLn` command on a separate line. The second `do` is not necessary (in fact, it is necessary not to have it). Additionally, you should know that the compiler views hard tabs as padding out to the next eight-space boundary; so although things look correctly indented here on SO, your code's mixture of tabs and spaces is incorrect. I recommend either using a single tab at the beginning of each line in the `do` block or converting all tabs to spaces. See also [my diatribe on tab styles](http://dmwit.com/tabs). So:

```
main = do 
        args <- getArgs  --Getting first arg
        putStrLn("Hello," ++args!!0)
        args1 <- getArgs
        putStrLn("Hello," ++args1!!1)  --Getting second arg
```

This is the smallest change needed to make things work. Additionally, since I see no reason to believe the arguments will change between the two calls to `getArgs`, you may as well omit the second call and simply reuse `args`:

```
main = do 
        args <- getArgs
        putStrLn("Hello," ++args!!0)
        putStrLn("Hello," ++args!!1)
```

Comment: Thank  you so much Daniel   for your time and article....it works finally after  configuring my  editor   *Main> :!hellome.exe  frank Erick
Hello,frank
Hello,Erick